# Get full file path from HTML5 drag and drop and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

Is there any way to get full path of dropped file in HTML5. What I am doing is,

```
$('.drop_target').on(
            {
                'dragover': function(e) {
                console.log('dragover');
                e.preventDefault();
            },
                'drop': function(e) {
                var file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;          
                console.log(file);
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```

I want to use this code in localhost application, so I can make any type of changes required, either in browser or in computer.

**EDIT**

Everywhere on the internet there are posts saying, due to security reasons full paths are disabled by browsers. Is there any way I can un-secure my own pc and make full path works!!

Comment: I don't think there is a way to "un-secure" this for a specific machine. At least I've never heard of such a configuration setting in any browser I know of.

Comment: @Pekka웃, yup I spent my last four hours on Google to find out the solution. At last I came here.

Answer (score 2):

OK, It's strange to answer my own question, but I got one workaround which is 100% working solution to my problem. The answer is mozilla's file.mozFullPath property.

```
console.log(file.mozFullPath)
```

It will only work for firefox browser. I hope there may be one universal sollution to this problem.

**EDIT**

Sorry, my mistake. In latest releases of firefox (Firefox 17 and so on) file.mozFullPath gives full path, but in console It returns empty string. So it will not work for latest firefox versions.